# What is the effect of ' \n'?

Tags: c, stm32

I have caused an effect which I really don't understand:

```
char buffer[6];
UINT i =  adc_getADCValue(6);

int j = 0;
for ( j = 0 ;j <4;j++){
buffer[3-j] = (UINT) ((i%10UL)+'0');
    i /=10;
}
buffer[4] = '\n';
buffer[5] = '\0';
localprint(buffer); // print  messages on terminal using COM port
```

it works [image: terminal]

my question is why is the output by using `\n` oblique?  I was hopping simulating the`printf` function . I'm using STM32f103xx uC.

Comment: Use `\r\n` instead. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: Or change the PuTTY settings - click on under "Terminal", then enable "Implicit CR in every LF", and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @SolarBear thanks for your comment , thanks to psmears too. If you put that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: C presumably has some constant you can use to add the platform-appropriate EOL character(s).

Comment: @meagar -  in this case the execution platform and the displaying one are different, so the compiler can't be of much direct help since it doesn't know about the latter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah, yes, I didn't clue in that this is a putty session.

Comment: In spite of everyone's suggestion to explicitly write `\r\n`, I suggest modifying your `printf` function to output it for you when you get just a `\n` so you can write normal looking C.  Couple more quick tips:  If you name your function `printf` beware of the compiler trying to substitute `puts` for `printf`. Easiest way around this is to rename the printf.  Also, for what it's worth, here's a good `printf` for this exact purpose (only dependency is stdarg.h):  http://geezer.osdevbrasil.net/osd/libc/printf.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all question of backwards compatibility. In Windows you need to use `\r\n` instead of simply `n`, which is the UNIX way of doing the same thing.

See [this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n) as well as @Bruce's post for more information.

Answer (score 6):

`\n`is next line (Line Feed - LF) and `\r` is carriage return (CR) on old printers.

Your terminal is configured to behave "à la" windows, where next line is CR+LF. Hence sending only LF goes to next line, but not to the begin.

Unix usually uses only LF.

Either change the configuration of your terminal or change the code to use `\n\r`

Comment: Although `\n\r` would do the job, `\r\n` is much more common.

Comment: True, common combination is CR+LF

Comment: @Bruce thanks for your answer, but  \solarBear comment helped me the first !